# How to open a website when a Button is clicked in Android application?

Tags: android, url, button, browser, android-intent

I am designing an app, with several button for users to click on. Once button is clicked, user is directed to appropriate website. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "I am designing an app", do you mean an RCP app, or an eclipse app not based on RCP but based on the IDE itself ?

Answer (score 45):

If you are talking about an RCP app, then what you need is the SWT `link` widget.

[Here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet183.java?view=co) is the official link event handler snippet.

**Update**

Here is  minimalist android application to connect to either superuser or stackoverflow with 2 buttons.

```
package ap.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class LinkButtons extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void goToSo (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    public void goToSu (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://superuser.com/");
    }

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

}
```

And here is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/select" />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:autoLink="web" android:cursorVisible="true" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/button_so" android:text="StackOverflow" android:linksClickable="true" android:onClick="goToSo"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="SuperUser" android:autoLink="web" android:clickable="true" android:id="@+id/button_su" android:onClick="goToSu"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am having troubles typing for some reason. Here is what I got so far: I added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"></uses-sdk> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to the manifest. I added a button in layout, in the place where you can actually see the button. res> drawable >layout>main. Now what do I do? Thanks again!

Comment: I am talking about an Eclipse App. I honestly don't know what is it based on.I hope it's based on my future success. I just downloaded Eclipse, it's working for developing very simple apps like, when user opens my app, it immediately directs user to a website. But I want to give user a choice to pick from several buttons to go to appropriate website. For example, if you are hungry and want to pick a place to eat, choose McDonald's, Burger King , Subway . So I want him to click on one of those buttons and connect to appropriate website

Comment: I think, what you mean is: an android app based on the android sdk with the eclipse IDE. I'll add the android tag.

Answer (score 28):

In your Java file write the following piece of code...

```
ImageView Button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonsId);

Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yourURL.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a workable answer.

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.tutorial.todolist"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"></uses-sdk>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".todolist"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

### todolist.java

```
package com.tutorial.todolist;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class todolist extends Activity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clickme);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.anddev.org"));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
             }
        });
    }
}
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_clickme" 
      android:text="Click me..." 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Import `import android.net.Uri;`

```
Intent openURL = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
openURL.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
startActivity(openURL);
```

or it can be done using,

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourID);

textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.typeyourURL.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ImageView Button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button);

Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com/");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your button's click listener:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    try {
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

If you have a website url as a variable instead of hardcoded string then don't forget to handle an ActivityNotFoundException and show error. Or you may receive invalid url and app will simply crash. (Pass random string instead of `url` variable and see for youself )

Answer (score 3):

I just need one line to show a website in my app:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://match4app.com")));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this on your button click activity

```
Intent webOpen = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            WebOpen.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
```

and import this on your code

```
import android.net.Uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView1;
Button google; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.google);
    google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");

      }
});        
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the buttons in anchors that href to the appropriate website.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="button" value="Button" />
</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="button" value="Button" />
</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="button" value="Button" />
</a>
```

When the user clicks the button (input) they are directed to the destination specified in the href property of the anchor.

Edit: Oops, I didn't read "Eclipse" in the question title. My mistake.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read that you are working with Eclipse. Ignore my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I put your answer into Eclipse and it doesn't read it right

Comment: even if it's html. you cant just wrap the button with the anchor tag.