# How to create Android application with button that goes to website?

Tags: android, url, button, browser, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open a website when a Button is clicked in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026349/how-to-open-a-website-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-application)

So I'm new to this, and I've searched, but it seems like all the answers are old, so please don't just link me to another thread. Also try to be as as descriptive as possible since I'm learning!

Question:
How can I create an android application on eclipse with android sdk that has one button that opens the browser and goes to a specific site. Thanks

-Techno

Comment: Do better research and don't tell people not to link answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026626/1067211 That link is from only a year and a half ago and should still be perfectly valid.

Comment: I did it exactly and it didn't work.... and certainly there has to be an easier way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two main parts to your application, a layout xml file and a Java Activity. The xml will contain a parent layout and a button. The Java file will set the content view to the layout contained in your xml file, pull out a reference to your Button object and set a click listener on it to get a callback when it is pressed by the user. Inside the callback you'll use an Intent to launch the browser and open up to a given url.

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button webBtn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webBtn);
        webBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            /**************************
             * This Intent will tell the System
             * that we want to view something
             * in this case we are telling it that
             * we want to view the URL that we 
             * pass as the second parameter. 
             * it will search thru the applications
             * on the device and find the one(s)
             * that can display this type of content.
             * If there are multiples it will prompt
             * the user to choose which one they'd like
             * to use.
             ***************************/
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "https://www.google.com");
            startActivity(i);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more research. I understand that you are learning (we all started somewhere right?), but that does not mean it gives you a pass to not do your homework.  @Tim's answer should do it but here are some more resources to help you at not only for this problem but for more problems you might come across:
-Android books: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443374/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-mobile-application-developmentandroid-that-is-exe/11443637#11443637) as well as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development).
-Android development site: http://developer.android.com/index.html
-This site 
-And of course youtube
I understand this does not directly answer your question but hopefully it will help you find the answer yourself (plus it was to long to fit in a comment)!