# Supplied button click method is not being found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, logcat

I am a newbie, and plus this is my first post
I hope i am clear with my problem and i really hope that someone can help me.

First of all, i am trying to make a simple page with some buttons, one of those button need to redirect me to a webpage.
But my problem was that i didnt knew how to make a redirect-button so i have take a look at this one: [How to open a website when a Button is clicked in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026349/how-to-open-a-website-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-application)

As i was following i seriously had many trouble.
i even didnt knew where to put them.
But after googleing and reading on the Android site i was able to do this, yay :)

Anyway, i still had litte problems, 
this line gave it to be exact.

```
public class LinkButtons extends Activity {
```

i changed this to:

```
class LinkButtons extends Activity {
```

and i was able to go, but not sure if it was a good idea...

i made the buttons on the XML but it gives me a warning (something about need to be hardcoded?) 
I ignored this one because i still was able to see the button with the text.

when i start the program it works fine, but when i touch this button (with need to redirect me to a webpage) the program stops for few seconds, and exits, and says "the process (my program) has stopped"

and in the Logcat i see this:

```
11-07 00:22:06.580: D/ActivityThread(30706): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
11-07 00:22:06.580: D/ActivityThread(30706): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
11-07 00:22:06.580: D/ActivityThread(30706): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
11-07 00:22:06.780: D/libEGL(30706): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
11-07 00:22:06.800: D/libEGL(30706): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
11-07 00:22:06.810: D/libEGL(30706): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_RB1.04.01.01.45.000_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): Local Branch: 
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3.1
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): Local Patches: NONE
11-07 00:22:06.820: I/Adreno200-EGL(30706): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
11-07 00:22:06.850: D/OpenGLRenderer(30706): Enabling debug mode 0
11-07 00:22:16.850: D/AndroidRuntime(30706): Shutting down VM
11-07 00:22:16.850: W/dalvikvm(30706): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eb6438)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method goToSu(View) in the activity class com.example.[need to remove this part, sorry].FullscreenActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_su'
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3667)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: goToSu [class android.view.View]
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
11-07 00:22:16.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    ... 11 more
```

What should i do now? or how do i fix this?

i appreciate any reply.

PS: I have added that .java code in my current one, this is okay right?
Or did i had to make another .java file?

P.P.S: Like i said, im a very newbie, if you gonna tell a advanced story, please explain...
Thanks,

EDIT:

Here is the code, Java and XML;

on the top of java;

```
    package com.example.[removed];
import com.example.[removed].util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
```

then

```
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                class LinkButtons extends Activity {

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
                    }

                    public void goToSo (View view) {
                        goToUrl ( "https://stackoverflow.com/");
                    }

                    public void goToSu (View view) {
                        goToUrl ( "http://superuser.com/");
                    }

                    private void goToUrl (String url) {
                        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
                        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                        startActivity(launchBrowser);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
```

and then XML

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_so"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToSo"

            android:text="StackOverflow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_su"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToSu"
            android:text="SuperUser" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The method `goToSu` cannot be found. Edit your question to include your code so we can look through and see why.

Comment: i have edited my post, it should give you more information now.
i am a bit confused, why it doesnt work

Comment: You've shown the definition of your LinkButtons class, but you have not shown where you have instantiated it. Where have you created an object of type LinkButtons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you declared your `onClick()` on your `Button` in xml which is fine. But you are missing the method that you declared in `android:onClick="goToSu"`. Add this method in your `Activity`.

```
public void goTuSu(View v)
{
     // your code
}
```

In the link you posted, you were obviously following the answer by Alain Pannetier who has this method in that answer

```
public void goToSu (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://superuser.com/");
}
```

**Edit**

Also from the answer you linked to is this method

```
 private void goToUrl (String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

which is called from `goToSu()`. `goToUrl()` is a custom method...not part of the Android framework.

You can see how the `onClick()` should be implemented through xml in the [Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.htmlv)

Comment: i surely want to add this simple code but i am getting confused on the line ///your code, what kind of code do i need to type?

Comment: Whatever code you need to run. As in the other example they call a method `goToUrl()`

Comment: I dont realy see a way that this should work, the only thing what is changed is ''view'' to v (why?)

Comment: That parameter can be called whatever you choose...I usually use `v` that person used `view`. The point is that you don't have that function in your code and that is the reason for the error.

Comment: aah, that cleared up a bit.
But i am still very confused, should i usue something with onClick() to make the process work?

Comment: No, if you have that function defined for your `Button` in your xml then when you click the `Button`, whatever is inside of that function should run

Comment: But i didnt defined anyhting for this button and i have no idea how to.
so i really dont know what you are exactly telling me.
its only getting more confusing for me.
Cant you give me just a very small and basic example?

Comment: I thought I did. In your `layout` file (`activity_fullscreen`, I'm assuming is what you posted) you have `android:onClick="goToSu"` for your `Button`. That defines an `onClick` event for the `Button`. Which means, when it is clicked it should call the function `goToSu(View v)`

Comment: so if im understanding right, on my post i made exactly what you are telling me right now.
The android:onClick="goToSu" is calling public void goToSo (View view) with has a URL inside of it { goToUrl ( "http://stackoverflow.com/");

But it doenst show up!?

Comment: See my edit. `goToSu()` calls another method, `goToUrl()` where the url is fetched

Comment: well, it was hard to understand but i finnaly got it to work, thank you!
I still have quastions, but not very close to this topic, should i create new one or just ask here?

Comment: If its unrelated then you should make a new post with relevant code and error messages/logcat

Answer (score 0):

wtsang02's answer is good, but falls a tiny bit short.

Don't use the android:onclick attribute in the xml for your layouts.  It is a nightmare to maintain.

Just do it in the activity's onCreate method.

in onCreate...

Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
   mButtonsetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }});
```

Comment: "Don't use the android:onclick attribute in the xml for your layouts. It is a nightmare to maintain." this is very bad advice, IMHO. It is very easy to maintain and often leads to cleaner code.

Comment: I respect your opinion, and still disagree with it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, if its a good idea (for you) where should i put this? just in the XML?

Comment: No. This belongs in the java code of your Activity.