# How do I make a button take me to a website in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'am learning how to code and I don't know how to make a button in Android Studio take me to website. And how can I make a button play a audio in reverse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026626/5182321

Comment: I think you should split this to two question (the first for button go to webview and second for play audio)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm: chk for audio part

Answer (score 1):

The web page part is easy:

```
public void launchAbout(View view){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://dpoisn.com/demos/AndroidDev/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

That function will do it.  That will launch the default browser to whatever page you specify.

Of course you'll need a button to call the function:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="launchAbout"
        android:text="About" />
```

The bit about the reverse audio, I'll have to leave for someone else.

Comment: All this i would put in my main activity or my content_main.xml

Comment: The Java goes in the activity.   The button goes in the xml.